# I am trying to make a small tokenizer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a tokenzir in js but i noticed that the "+" is not included in the result as i wanted
what is the error in this code

```
var a=String.raw`(0.34+4+5.5++4() )`
function tokenizer(a){var b=0;d=[];e="";
while(b<a.length){var c=a[b];
    if(c=="+"){d.push("+");c=a[++b];continue;}
    if(c=="("){d.push(c);b++;continue;}
    if(c==")"){d.push(c);b++;continue;}
    if(c==" "||c=="\n"||c=="\t"){b++;continue;}
    if(/[0-9.]/.test(c)==true){while(/[0-9.]/.test(c)==true){e+=c;c=a[++b]};d.push(e);e="";b++;continue}
}
return d;
}
console.log(tokenizer(a))//result =["(", "0.34", "4", "5.5", "+", "4", ")", ")"]
```

the result that i wish u ["(", "0.34","+", "4","+", "5.5","+, "+", "4", ")", ")"]

Comment: Do not use all the `[++b]` and `[b++]` indexing and incrementing at the same time. It makes the code more difficult to read and easy to make a mistake, like in your case - removing the very last `b++` (the one before `continue`) fixes the problem

Comment: Just a tip, you should really try to ask a question in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment an answer:

Do not use all the `[++b]` and `[b++]` indexing and incrementing at the same time. It makes the code more difficult to read and easy to make a mistake, like in your case - removing the very last `b++` (the one before continue) fixes the problem (see below). *I prefer* to use the index and increment is after the command (or before for the case of `++b`)

Working code:

```js
var a=String.raw`(0.34+4+5.5++4() )`
function tokenizer(a){var b=0;d=[];e="";
    while(b<a.length){var c=a[b];
            if(c=="+"){d.push("+");c=a[++b];continue;}
            if(c=="("){d.push(c);b++;continue;}
            if(c==")"){d.push(c);b++;continue;}
            if(c==" "||c=="\n"||c=="\t"){b++;continue;}
            if(/[0-9.]/.test(c)==true){while(/[0-9.]/.test(c)==true){e+=c;c=a[++b]};d.push(e);e="";continue}
    }
    return d;
}
console.log(tokenizer(a))
```

Output:

```
[
  '(', '0.34', '+',
  '4', '+',    '5.5',
  '+', '+',    '4',
  '(', ')',    ')'
]
```

What *I think* also makes the code cleaner:

- indentation and splitting the code into more lines, one command per line
- using meaningful variable names. Again, you save some space and writing, but for the price of less readable code. And consequently for the price of more difficult debugging :-)